# Set "Ubuntu On Xorg" by default globally but without preventing the choice of Wayland

Tags: xorg, wayland, ubuntu-22.04

On this site:

https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/quick-docs/configuring-xorg-as-default-gnome-session/

I was told the way to set `Ubuntu on Xorg` by default in the file `/etc/gdm3/custom.conf`:

```
# GDM configuration storage
#
# See /usr/share/gdm/gdm.schemas for a list of available options.

[daemon]
# Uncomment the line below to force the login screen to use Xorg
#WaylandEnable=false

# Enabling automatic login
#  AutomaticLoginEnable = true
#  AutomaticLogin = user1

# Enabling timed login
#  TimedLoginEnable = true
#  TimedLogin = user1
#  TimedLoginDelay = 10

DefaultSession=ubuntu-xorg.desktop

[security]

[xdmcp]

[chooser]

[debug]
# Uncomment the line below to turn on debugging
# More verbose logs
# Additionally lets the X server dump core if it crashes
#Enable=true
```

But it doesn't work.
The name `ubuntu-xorg.desktop` I took it from the path `/usr/share/xsessions`.
Uncommenting (as the guide explains) or not the `WaylandEnable=false` line, the `DefaultSession=ubuntu-xorg.desktop` line has no effect.

I don't want the option `Wayland` to disappear (uncommenting the line `WaylandEnable=false`), I just want that when creating any user (therefore for all users, therefore globally) `Ubuntu on Xorg` is selected as default is not `Ubuntu` (Ubuntu on Wayland).
Which file should I go to touch?

Don't tell me `/var/lib/AccountService/users/<user>` because I've already pointed out that I want to set this option globally but I don't want a way that uses the `/usr/local/sbin/adduser.local` file to do this if there is an already foreseen and more appropriate method.